# Acceder al valor en una consulta con Node js - Adonsi Js

Tags: base-de-datos, nodejs

Quiero acceder al valor en una consulta Node.js
Para dejar más claro lo que necesito doy en ejemplo en Laravel

```
$usuario= DB::table('usuarios')
                ->where('idUsuario', '=', 1)
                ->get();

echo $usuario[0]->nombreUsuario
```

Pero en Node Js cómo es, no logro encontrar algo que funcione

```
const usuarios = Database
                .table('usuarios')
                .select('idUsuario', 'nombresUsuario')

console.log(usuarios.idUsuario)
```

esto no funciona

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que aclarar que framework de acceso a base de datos estas usando

Comment: Estoy haciendo las consultas con el framework Adonis.js

Comment: los comandos de ese framework con asíncronos por lo que debes usar [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) o usarlos como promesas usando el método `then`. En todos los ejemplos del framework se usan los operadores.

Comment: Soy nuevo tanto en node js como su framework adonis, podrías darme un pequeño ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: `const usuarios = await Database.table('usuarios').....` o `Database           .table('usuarios').select(...).then(usuarios => /* codigo */)` cualquiera de los 2 sirve